# Exception when trying to take persistable uri permission for uri returned by PhotoPicker API

Tags: android

I am encountering a runtime issue when using the PhotoPicker API, specifically on real devices (e.g. Samsung Galaxy S9, Redmi 9…) with Android 10 (API 29) and below, where the PhotoPicker falls back to the ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT intent as far as I understand. The app throws the following exception:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: No persistable permission grants found for UID 10574 and Uri 0 @ content://media/external/file/2
```

This occurs when trying to take persistable URI permission for the URI returned by the PhotoPicker. Below is the relevant code snippet, which follows the implementation from the [PhotoPicker Docs](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/photopicker):

```
// Code from Fragment
val pickMedia = registerForActivityResult(PickVisualMedia()) { uri ->
    if (uri != null) {
        val flag = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
        requireContext().contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(uri, flag)
    } else {
        Log.d("PhotoPicker", "No media selected")
    }
}

pickMedia.launch(PickVisualMediaRequest(PickVisualMedia.ImageOnly))
```

Everything works fine on emulators, it's just on real devices where this happens. I really can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, or maybe my understanding of URIs is wrong or something. Has anyone else encountered a similar issue with the PhotoPicker API? Any tips or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much!

Below is the full error message:

```
11-29 15:49:49.564 E/AndroidRuntime(10810): Process: xyz.some_app, PID: 10810
11-29 15:49:49.564 E/AndroidRuntime(10810): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=281583204, result=-1, data=Intent { flg=0x1 launchParam=MultiScreenLaunchParams { mDisplayId=0 mBaseDisplayId=0 mFlags=0 } clip={image/* video/* U:content://media/external/file/2} }} to activity {xyz.some_app/xyz.some_app.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: No persistable permission grants found for UID 10574 and Uri 0 @ content://media/external/file/2
11-29 15:49:49.564 E/AndroidRuntime(10810):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4520)
11-29 15:49:49.564 E/AndroidRuntime(10810):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4563)
11-29 15:49:49.564 E/AndroidRuntime(10810):     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap22(ActivityThread.java)
11-29 15:49:49.564 E/AndroidRuntime(10810):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1698)
11-29 15:49:49.564 E/AndroidRuntime(10810):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-29 15:49:49.564 E/AndroidRuntime(10810):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
11-29 15:49:49.564 E/AndroidRuntime(10810):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
11-29 15:49:49.564 E/AndroidRuntime(10810):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-29 15:49:49.564 E/AndroidRuntime(10810):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
11-29 15:49:49.564 E/AndroidRuntime(10810):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
11-29 15:49:49.564 E/AndroidRuntime(10810): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: No persistable permission grants found for UID 10574 and Uri 0 @ content://media/external/file/2
11-29 15:49:49.564 E/AndroidRuntime(10810):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1693)
11-29 15:49:49.564 E/AndroidRuntime(10810):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1646)
11-29 15:49:49.564 E/AndroidRuntime(10810):     at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.takePersistableUriPermission(ActivityManagerNative.java:5832)
11-29 15:49:49.564 E/AndroidRuntime(10810):     at android.content.ContentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(ContentResolver.java:1799)
11-29 15:49:49.564 E/AndroidRuntime(10810):     at ae.b0.a(SourceFile:54)
11-29 15:49:49.564 E/AndroidRuntime(10810):     at androidx.activity.result.f.a(SourceFile:45)
11-29 15:49:49.564 E/AndroidRuntime(10810):     at androidx.activity.l.onActivityResult(SourceFile)
11-29 15:49:49.564 E/AndroidRuntime(10810):     at androidx.fragment.app.c0.onActivityResult(SourceFile)
11-29 15:49:49.564 E/AndroidRuntime(10810):     at xyz.some_app.MainActivity.onActivityResult(SourceFile)
11-29 15:49:49.564 E/AndroidRuntime(10810):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7280)
11-29 15:49:49.564 E/AndroidRuntime(10810):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4516)
```

Answer (score 5):

> where the PhotoPicker falls back to the ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT intent as far as I understand

Not necessarily. There are a few possibilities based on the now-current [implementation](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:activity/activity/src/main/java/androidx/activity/result/contract/ActivityResultContracts.kt;l=638?q=PickVisualMedia&sq=&ss=androidx):

```kotlin
        override fun createIntent(context: Context, input: PickVisualMediaRequest): Intent {
            // Check if Photo Picker is available on the device
            return if (isSystemPickerAvailable()) {
                Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_PICK_IMAGES).apply {
                    type = getVisualMimeType(input.mediaType)
                }
            } else if (isSystemFallbackPickerAvailable(context)) {
                val fallbackPicker = checkNotNull(getSystemFallbackPicker(context)).activityInfo
                Intent(ACTION_SYSTEM_FALLBACK_PICK_IMAGES).apply {
                    setClassName(fallbackPicker.applicationInfo.packageName, fallbackPicker.name)
                    type = getVisualMimeType(input.mediaType)
                }
            } else if (isGmsPickerAvailable(context)) {
                val gmsPicker = checkNotNull(getGmsPicker(context)).activityInfo
                Intent(GMS_ACTION_PICK_IMAGES).apply {
                    setClassName(gmsPicker.applicationInfo.packageName, gmsPicker.name)
                    type = getVisualMimeType(input.mediaType)
                }
            } else {
                // For older devices running KitKat and higher and devices running Android 12
                // and 13 without the SDK extension that includes the Photo Picker, rely on the
                // ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT intent
                Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT).apply {
                    type = getVisualMimeType(input.mediaType)

                    if (type == null) {
                        // ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT requires to set this parameter when launching the
                        // intent with multiple mime types
                        type = "*/*"
                        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, arrayOf("image/*", "video/*"))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The device manufacturer (or, in theory, third parties) could provide an implementation of `ACTION_SYSTEM_FALLBACK_PICK_IMAGES`. Some devices, via Play Services, may have an implementation of `GMS_ACTION_PICK_IMAGES`. Neither of these are necessarily going to grant persistable `Uri` permissions.

So, you're welcome to *try* to get the persistable `Uri` permission, but you need to handle the case where one is not offered to you.

Comment: So since I need long-term access to the image, my best bet would be to either save the image to the app-specific storage or check if the PhotoPicker is not available and just use the `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` intent myself to get around the other fallbacks, right?

Comment: @nitnatsnoK: Yes. However, "check if the PhotoPicker is not available" may require you to clone some code from `PickVisualMedia`. What you want is `isSystemPickerAvailable()`, which is `internal`, and while it is presently exposed via the parameter-less form of `isPhotoPickerAvailable()`, that is `@Deprecated`. Also, I don't know that the system picker is documented to say that persistable `Uri` permissions should be available. That means device manufacturers might tweak the picker and not offer persistable permissions as a side-effect of those tweaks.

Comment: @CommonsWare what's the point of this so-called simple photo picker if there are still so many caveats to be handled by the dev?

Comment: @Asim: You would have to ask Google. Note that, AFAIK, this question only deals with one caveat: you are not guaranteed to be able to get persistable `Uri` permission for the resulting photo(s).

Comment: @CommonsWare related to the question: If I'm trying to get an image using this new Photo Picker, could you point me to exactly what code I should write? Been on it for hours now and keep getting 'file not found' or 'no persistable permission'.

Comment: Managed to do it by using the code suggested by @CommonsWare. Ran into another issue where the `intent` returned by `onActivityResult` only had `ClipData`. Fixed that by `data.getClipData().getItemAt(0).getUri()`.

Comment: @Asim: I am a bit surprised you encountered a problem there, as [`PickVisualMedia` seems to handle that case](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:activity/activity/src/main/java/androidx/activity/result/contract/ActivityResultContracts.kt;l=826-837?q=PickVisualMedia&ss=androidx). Regardless, I am glad that you got it working!